# How to read an XPS (Fixed page) file and show in UI using Silverlight 

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, xpsdocument

I am trying to read an XPS file and show it using Silverlight.

I don't have much experience with Silverlight but I have WPF knowledge. How do I view an XPS (Fixed Document) in Silverlight?

I am able to view XPS(Fixed Document) in WPF, but not in Silverlight. Is there any way to do that in Silverlight?

Any reply will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, how would you do it with WPF?

Comment: You've updated a 3-month-old question to change the question entirely.  Why not post a new question?!

Comment: @Dan: Sorry, but what I asked earlier is very similar to what I changed now. I only modified the question to explain the scenario briefly and want to add an attention to everyone who involved in stackoverflow.

Comment: Your update says "Can anybody tell me how Silverlight differ from WPF and on which basis we have to go for Silverlight?"  That's quite a change!

Comment: @Dan: Yeah I agree, that is only I changed and it is because I wanted to know why people prefers silverlight if WPF can do the same easily?

As this XPS reading scenario, I can do in WPF.

Comment: Yes, but that is a *different question*.  Repost!

Comment: @dan yes, the added extra bit at the bottom is a new question; @SharpUrBrain thanks for rolling back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been a few articles on the topic (such as [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/05/22/lighting-up-the-xml-paper-specification-proof-of-concept-xps-reader-for-silverlight.aspx)), but none of them are really complete.  Your best bet (although it's a commercial product) would be the [Document Toolkit](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/documenttoolkit) from First Floor Software (the same guy that wrote Silverlight Spy).  I haven't used it myself, but AFAIK it's the only real solution available for Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Chris but while I ran that sample application at the run time it is showing error :-The Remote Server Returned an Error:Not Found

Comment: It's a very old article (from mid-2007), so I was doubtful you could use it as is.  The Document Toolkit is your best bet.

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: AFAIK MS didn't deliver anything in the framework to solve your needs.  You'll either have to make it yourself or buy it made from someone else.  Purchasing code will probably be cheaper and more reliable than making it, right now.